# how to retrieve a value if a checkbox is checked

Tags: php, custom-field

So i have this checkbox:

```
$fm = new Fieldmanager_Checkbox( 'Artigo em actualização', array( 'name' => 'updating' ) );
$fm->add_meta_box( 'Estado', 'post', 'side' );
```

And if its checked i need to add an html like this:

```
} elseif ( $in_update ) {
                        echo '<span class="tag--alert tag--featured">Em Actualização</span>';
                }
```

I just dont know how to define this $in_update in order to get the value of the checkbox inside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the post meta value that Fieldmanager writes to your database for the checkbox. [This answer can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856914/fieldmanager-wordpress-plugin).

Then you can properly set `$in_update` and do this test:

```
elseif ( /* VALUE WHEN YOUR CHECKBOX IS CHECKED */ == $in_update ) {
    echo '<span class="...';
}
```